# Scope resolution operator on class variables

Tags: php, oop

I am curious as to why using the scope resolution operator on class variables causes a fatal php error, and if there is a way around it.

For example:

```
<?php
class StaticTest
{
    public static function output()
    {
        echo "Output called<br />";
    }
}
Class Test
{
    public $reference;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this -> reference = new StaticTest;
    }

}

$static_test = new StaticTest;
$static_test::output(); //works as intended

$test = new Test;
$test -> reference::output(); //Unexpcted T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM

$direct_reference = $test -> reference;
$direct_reference::output(); //works, closest solution i have found, but requires the extra line of code / variable
?>
```

Comment: PHP has all sorts of silly "this can't go after that" rules/bugs. You'll just have to use a variable.

Comment: `{$test -> reference}::output();`? Braces are always good when there's potential ambiguity...

Comment: does it work if you try `($test -> reference)::output()`?

Comment: Interestingly in bins out at the first `::` in 5.2: http://codepad.viper-7.com/xCQctX, and the `{}` doesn't work :-( http://codepad.viper-7.com/5OfpSa

Comment: I am surprised that `$static_test::output();` works at all.

Comment: "Unexpcted T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM" - my favorite error

Comment: @MarkEirich I can see why it would be useful to allow that. You could have a variable that would be populated by an object that is an instance of one of several classes, all of which define a `public static function output()`, and it's nice to be able to call it without having to first extract the name of the class.

Comment: @Eric What an odd thing to say... [`Notice: Undefined variable: in`](http://codepad.viper-7.com/7xTZ8Z) is clearly better. Although I do like a good Paamayim Nekudoayim. Good page title separators. Nothing like a bit of hebrew to brighten the day.

Comment: @Eric or [this](http://codepad.viper-7.com/0oElTc)

Comment: @DaveRandom: That made my day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your only concern is the number of lines of code and the extra variable, here's how you can do it in one line, without creating any variables:

```
call_user_func(array(get_class($test->reference), 'output'));
```

Which, I believe, is equivalent to:

```
$direct_reference = $test->reference;
$direct_reference::output();
```

Comment: Wow, nasty. I like the lateral thinking though, +1

Comment: I think it's nasty too, but the OP's only complaint about it the other way was "requires the extra line of code / variable" and I've solved that :-P